# With VI search and replace how do I replace the text within the last two sets of single quotes?

Tags: vim, replace, vi

I have a lot of lines like this:

```
{ id: 22, name: 'Alice', score: 123, city: 'Atlanta', birthday: '1981/12/03'},
```

I want to use a VI (gvim to be exact) search and replace and empty the last two sets of single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use search and replace, you can do this:

```
:%s/city: '.\{-}'/city: ''
```

and the same for the birthday field

```
:%s/birthday: '.\{-}'/birthday: ''
```

the "\{-}" is the same as "*" but uses de shortest match first algorithm. (see :help non-greedy)

if you really like do this in a single command:

```
%s/\(city:\|birthday:\) '.\{-}'/\1 ''/g
```

"city:" and "birthday:" are matched as a sub-expression with the \( and \), then you can use the \1 (means the first sub-expression) in the substitute string, the end g option is needed to make more than one substitution in a single line.

Comment: Accepting your answer because you answered my direct question "using search and replace"

Answer (score 7):

you can use `:normal` cmd, sometimes it comes easier than the `:s`. for your example:

```
:norm! $F'di'3;.
```

will change your line into:

```
{ id: 22, name: 'Alice', score: 123, city: '', birthday: ''},
```

If you want to do this on all lines, you just `:%norm! ....`. You can combine the `norm` cmd with `:g` too, e.g. you want to do this transform on all lines with `name:`

```
:g/name:/norm! ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a macro to achieve that. To start recording a macro, hit `q` followed by a register where you want to save it (for example under `a` register). Do it in command mode.

```
$F'di';;di'j
```

$ - go to the end of line 
F' - search backwards for ' 
di' - delete what is between single quotes 
;; - go to the previous single quotes 
di' - delete again 
j - go to line below

Finish a macro by hitting again q. Then, to apply a macro on a single line hit `@a`. To apply a macro on all lines type `:%norm! @a`

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the following regex:

```
:%s/'[^']\+'\([^']\+\)'[^']\+'}/''\1''}
```